# in grep, why does it need to escape [ while not for ]

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep

there is one line in file `data`, as

> [overall], ....

when using `grep` to obtain this line, I find this can be done only by

> grep "\[overall]" data

just out of curiosity, Why does it need to escape `[` while not for `]`.

EDIT: this is tested on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `]` only has any special meaning when it has already been preceded by a `[` that was not escaped.

You can have fun (if you've got the right, somewhat distorted, mindset) with:

```
grep '[][-]' ...
```

This searches for `]`, `[` or `-`.  You have to be careful with the placement of `]`; it must go at the start of the character class.  You have to be careful with the placement of `-`; it must go at the start or end of the class.  And the caret that negates a class must go first.

```
grep '[^][-]' ...
```

Comment: +1 for gratuitous suggestion of geekly recreational activities... ;-P

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that without an opening [ to specify a character class, the closing ] has no meaning. So once you've escaped the opening bracket, the closing one doesn't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

I second Derek's and Jonathan's answers. Over the year, I found myself use `fgrep` more than `grep`. `fgrep` is the same as `grep -F` or `grep --fixed-strings`, in which the search term is just a string, not a regular expression. For example, if I want to search for `[overall]`:

```
fgrep "[overall]" file
```